# Making consecutive images only appear after the last disappear while hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

in a little project of mine I have several buttons, which when hovered display an image in another div. After hovering the first button, when hovering the second the first image is still there and both images show up.

What do I do for the second image only appear after the first as disappeared?

My JavaScript code:

```
$(".button").hover(function () {
    var iN = $(this).attr("id").charAt(6);
    $('#img'+ iN).fadeIn('slow');
},function() {
    var iN = $(this).attr("id").charAt(6);
   $('#img' + iN).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it, but it may not work in your use case. (If not, please add more detail to your question.)

Note that the example uses the jQuery "starts with" selector: `^=` to re-hide all elements where the ID begins with the letters `img`

```js
$('img').hide();

$(".button").hover(function () {
    var iN = $(this).attr("id").charAt(6);
    $('#img'+ iN).fadeIn('slow');
},function() {
    $('[id^=img]').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
div{height:100px;width:200px;border:1px solid orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="123456f" class="button">
  <img id="imgf" src="http://placeimg.com/200/100/nature" />
</div>
<div id="kittenc" class="button">
  <img id="imgc" src="http://placeimg.com/200/100/animals" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works great for me. Hope it helps :).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button").hover(function(){
    var buttonID = $(this).attr("id");
     $("#image").attr('src', 'images/pic'+ buttonID+".jpg");  
  });
});
```

```html
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "container">
<button id = "1" class = "button">Button1</button>
<button id = "2" class = "button">Button2</button>
<button id = "3" class = "button">Button3</button>
<button id = "4" class = "button">Button4</button>
</div>

<img id = "image" src="">
```

Answer (score 0):

In this Snippet we are:

- using the events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.
- using `toggleClass()`to control the `opacity` of the `<img>`s.
- synchronizing the mouse events fired by the buttons, by using `index()` to determine the button's position.
- matching the associated img to the button's index position by using `.eq()`.
- fading transition effects on `<img>`s are done by CSS properties `opacity` and `transition` which are tied into the classes `.on` and `.off`.

#### SNIPPET

```js
$('button').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
  var position = $(this).index();
  $('#gallery').find('img').eq(position).toggleClass('on off');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #CCC;
}
#gallery {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
}
img.off {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
}
img.on {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
}
img:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 17px;
}
button {
  width: 75px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border: 3px outset grey;
  color: 0ee;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<section id='gallery'>
  <img src='http://placehold.it/75x100/000/fff?text=1' class='off'>
  <img src='http://placehold.it/75x100/00f/eee?text=2' class='off'>
  <img src='http://placehold.it/75x100/0e0/111?text=3' class='off'>
  <img src='http://placehold.it/75x100/f00/fff?text=4' class='off'>
  <img src='http://placehold.it/75x100/fc0/000?text=5' class='off'>
  <img src='http://placehold.it/75x100/fff/000?text=6' class='off'>
</section>
<fieldset>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
  <button>6</button>
</fieldset>
```